# Images not showing up in reactnative

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native

I have images stored in a Meteor App I want to display, only text is showing up. 
Here is the component

```
 render(){

    const{nom, emails, picture} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log({picture})

    return(
      <View>
          <Card>
            <Image
            style={{width: 50, height: 60}}
            source={{uri: picture}}
            />
            <Text>{nom}</Text>
            <Text>{emails[0].email}</Text>
          </Card>
        </View>

      );
}
```

}

and the json file looks like this:

```
"picture":      "http://www2.assemblee-nationale.fr/static/tribun/15/photos/718902.jpg",
```

Comment: is `picture` an object or an uri?

Comment: it's an object, sorry very new to this...i mean it's in json file so {"picture"="http"}

Comment: Is `Card` properly rendering its children?

Comment: The url that you posted returns 404

Comment: Yes, I have {nom} displaying for ex

Comment: i have this url working http://www2.assemblee-nationale.fr/static/tribun/15/photos/718902.jpg but the image is still not showing up

Comment: Make sure the json file's url is correct, because the links you posted in the comment and in the question are different

Comment: Absolutely thank you! the second is correct and this is the one I have in he json file;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161247/discussion-between-mckuok-and-sonia).

Comment: Maybe it is because of non-secure 'http' protocol? try to fetch another image but with 'https' protocol

Comment: I got it sort it out! I added a "picture" in the json file but not in the db on the meteor app...!